# Changing link style onclick

Tags: javascript

I am currently experimenting with JavaScript and I'm having trouble changing the style of the links on my landing page. What I have is four boxes in the top right of the page that when clicked change the theme of the landing page. I was able to get the background and text to change when the boxes are clicked, but hyperlinks remain unchanged. I have read several other posts asking similar questions but I was unable to adapt the code to my situation.

I have tried using getElementById, and getElementByclassName but neither produced the result I was looking for. The getElementById was able to change one of the links but the rest remained unchanged. I'm guessing it only works on one link because the id can only be used once per page?

The current JavaScript code is written as four separate functions, but I was thinking perhaps it would be better to use one case statement?

I have left a link to jsfiddle, but for some reason the onclick function does not work at jsfiddle. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

http://jsfiddle.net/F4vte/

HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <form>
            <input type="button" id="color-box1"
                onclick="colorText1();">

            <input type="button" id="color-box2"
                onclick="colorText2();">

            <input type="button" id="color-box3"
                onclick="colorText3();">

            <input type="button" id="color-box4"
                onclick="colorText4();">
        </form>

        <div id="centerText">
            <h1 id="name">Donald Price</h1>
            <div id="underline"></div>
            <div id="nav">
                <a href="blog.html">Blog</a>
                <a href="projects.html">Projects</a>
                <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                <a href="resume.html">Resume</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

JavaScript

```
function colorText1(){
    document.getElementById("name").style.color="#A32DCA";
    document.getElementById("underline").style.color="#A32DCA";
    document.getElementById("nav").style.color="#A32DCA";
    document.bgColor = '#96CA2D';
}

function colorText2(){
    document.getElementById("name").style.color="#8FB299";
    document.getElementById("underline").style.color="#8FB299";
    document.bgColor = '#FFFFFF';
}

function colorText3(){
    document.getElementById("name").style.color="#484F5B";
    document.getElementById("underline").style.color="#484F5B";
    document.bgColor = '#4BB5C1';
}

function colorText4(){
    document.getElementById("name").style.color="#FFFFFF";
    document.getElementById("underline").style.color="#FFFFFF";
    document.bgColor = '#00191C';
}
```

CSS

```
body {
font-family:Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
font-size:62.5%;
width:960px;
padding-left:3px;
margin:auto;    
}

#underline {
border-bottom:3px solid;
}

#container {
width:50em;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
margin-top:30%;
z-index:2;
}

/*color box settings*/
#color-box1,#color-box2,#color-box3,#color-box4 {
position:absolute;
top:0;
width:50px;
height:50px;
float:left;
-webkit-transition:margin .5s ease-out;
-moz-transition:margin .5s ease-out;
-o-transition:margin .5s ease-out;
border-color:#B5E655;
border-style:solid;
margin:15px;
}

#color-box1:hover, #color-box2:hover, #color-box3:hover, #color-box4:hover {
    margin-top: 4px;
}

#color-box1 {
background-color:#96CA2D;
right:0;
}

#color-box2 {
right:50px;
background-color:#FFFFFF;
}

#color-box3 {
right:100px;
background-color:#4BB5C1;
}

#color-box4 {
right:150px;
background-color:#00191C;
}

#centerText {
width:50em;
text-align:center;
}

#nav {
padding:20px;
}

#nav a {
padding-left:2px;
font-size:20px;
text-align:center;

}

a:link {
color:#000;
text-decoration:none;
}

a:visited {
text-decoration:none;
color:#999;
}

a:hover {
text-decoration:none;
color:red;
}

a:active {
text-decoration:none;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from what @j08691 said about needing to run your existing script in the header,

just add `color:inherit;` to your `#nav a` selector in your css.

```
#nav a {
    padding-left:2px;
    font-size:20px;
    text-align:center;
    color:inherit; 
}
```

This way when you change the color of `#nav` that color will be inherited by your links (`a`).

<kbd>**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/F4vte/7/)**</kbd>

Comment: I had no idea you could (ab)use the <kbd> element to produce a cool-looking button like that.

Comment: What do you mean @Taymon?

Answer (score 0):

You can't just set the color of the  `div` to change the color of the links. You need to get the `a` elements and change their style. There are probably better ways to do this, but just to illustrate, you can iterate through the child nodes of the `div`:

```
function colorText1() {
    document.getElementById("name").style.color = "#A32DCA";
    document.getElementById("underline").style.color = "#A32DCA";
    var children = document.getElementById("nav").childNodes;
    for (var i=0; i < children.length; i++) {
        if (children[i].tagName == 'A') {
        children[i].style.color = "#A32DCA";
        }
    }
    document.bgColor = '#96CA2D';
}
```

See it working on the [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F4vte/6/).

Comment: I love this place! Two different answers and they both worked. I think I'll go with Brandon Boones' answer since it required less code. I didn't know about .childNodes.  Thanks a lot!